# Can't understand how this javascript code control flow?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is the code of which i am not able to understand the flow of and also how the value of i persist even after the for loop ends.

```js
var printNumTwo;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    console.log("now");
    
    printNumTwo = function() {
      console.log("inside");
      return i;
    };
    
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log(i);
}

console.log(printNumTwo());
```

The output of the program is

```
0
1
now
2
2
3
4
inside
2
```

Comment: JS Closure here !!!

Comment: `i` is declared with `let`, so it has block scope inside the loop - every iteration has a separate binding for `i`, and the iteration that has a function assigned to `printNumTwo` is when the `i` is `2`

Comment: Reopening because the dup you marked does not use `let` and thus does not explain this particular example.  This question deserves its own answer for its own circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

> reason of this behavior is Closures
>
> A closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner
>   function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is
>   created, at function creation time. [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```js
var printNumTwo;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    console.log("now");
    
    printNumTwo = function() {
      console.log("inside");
      return i;
    };
    
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log(i);
}

console.log('now calling printNumTwo()')
let s=printNumTwo();

console.log('now printing return value of printNumTwo()')

console.log('retrun value of PrintNumTwo is:'+s);
```